# Is it possible to disable editing for certain layers in a QGIS project?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, editing

I want to disable editing some (but not all) layers in one QGIS project, while still having them editable in a different project.

Is it possible to disable editing certain layers within a QGIS project without making the actual data read-only?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is possible to make a layer not editable in a specific project.

Open Project properties >  Data sources and check the option Read Only for the layers that you want to make not editable.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You can also use one line python script. Select a layer and run the script:

```
iface.activeLayer().setReadOnly(True)
```

According to the [documentation](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a95df5d62f2d49cec1ef332e9275c0ba9), if the layer is in editing, it returns `False`.

Comment: is it possible to set for selected layers at once ?

Comment: Afaik, there is no a method for that. Though, these one line codes could be useful: `[lyr.setReadOnly(False) for lyr in iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()]` or `list(map(lambda l: l.setReadOnly(True), iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()))`